# popup of web didn't show on webview android app

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, webview, livechat

i want show this website
https://www.tidio.com/talk/dc71bf5k0ncictpdhdyhujy2hzf9zn7x
in webview in my android app
it live chat
but the popup of live chat didn't show on Android app but it work on Google chrome

i create newe webview client and webchrome client

and i enabled java script in webview setting
and i enabled canjavascriptopenpopupautomaticly

but stil the popup didn't work
please help
and thank you
[the page in Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6lsC.jpg)

[the page in my webview android Pp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZbOl.jpg)

please help
and thank you all
sorry for my bad English
Best Regards